# Multiselect dropdown select items in between 2 selected items

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Iam working on multiselect dropdown using "select2.min.js" js file

it is working fine but i want to select item between already selected items i.e in attached screen shot i want to add "AAAA" in between "BBBB" and "DDDD" by clicking in between them and not by deleting "DDDD" and "FFFF" .

I need this as mandartory as part of our requirment. could any one help on this or sugges some other way doing this

[image: dropdownlist image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to add the option in the clicked part (before or after another already selected option) you need to:

- listen for click events on the option list
- on select2:select put the element in the right position

```js
$('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2().on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var aferEle = $(this).data('select2').$container.data('spanafter');

    var element = e.params.data.element;
    var $element = $(element);

    $element.detach();
    if (aferEle == null) {
        $(this).append($element);
    } else {
        $element.insertAfter($(this).find('option:contains("' + aferEle + '")'));
    }
    $(this).trigger("change");
}).data('select2').$container.on('click', function (e) {
            var spans = $(this).find('.select2-selection__choice').filter(function (idx, ele) {
                var x = ele.offsetLeft + ele.offsetWidth;
                var y = e.clientX;
                return x < y;
            });
            var spanafter = null;
            if (spans.length < $(this).find('.select2-selection__choice').length) {
                spanafter = spans.eq(spans.length-1).find('span:last').text();
            }
            $(this).data('spanafter', spanafter);
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;">
    <option>EEE</option>
    <option>CCC</option>
    <option>AAA</option>
    <option>BBB</option>
    <option>DDD</option>
    <option>FFF</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do we have any ather way .. because iam using the multi select drop down in modal popup the e.clientX is not accurate

Comment: @MounikaVadeghar How do you implement a modal dialog? Boostrap, jquery-ui...? Can you share your solution? Thanks